# azure function app (python) - How to check package versions in function app

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

We are working on building micro services using azure python function app, after deploying code to function app , is there way to quickly check versions of python packages used in function app ?

Thank you
Dyanesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is the Python Version check in Azure Function App, you can use the below cmdlet taken from [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/set-runtime-version?tabs=portal#manual-version-updates-on-linux):

```
az functionapp show -n HarisFunAppPython -g HariTestRG --query "siteConfig.linuxFxVersion"
(OR)
az functionapp config show --name HarisFunAppPython --resource-group HariTestRG --query 'linuxFxVersion'
```

[image]

If it is the python installed packages using pip, then use the command `pip list`:
[image]

To check the installed packages in Function App after deploying, Go to the Azure Function App > App Files > `requirements.txt`

[image]

Or Go to the Kudu Site of the Function app > Bash > Navigate to the below path to see the installed packages list of the deployed Function App:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, How did you download .Zip file to your local ?

Comment: When you deploy the function app, it will published as zip. After deploying, in the function app portal menu, go to Kudu Site > bash > you can find the deployed zip folder which shows what files and packages are deployed!